# segregate data and save according to date in a column in cumulative way

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a big csv file which have data according to date and i want to create a cumcount kind of files.Eg:

```
name    date
abc     01/01/2020
xyz     01/04/2020
dcd     01/04/2020
ddd     01/05/2020
fff     01/06/2020
ggg     01/12/2020
```

and i want to create milestone files and save them like first file will contain data having only 01/01/2020 date and save it and second file should have data 01/01/2020 and 01/04/2020 and save,, the third file should 01/01/2020, 01/04/2020 and 01/05/2020 date and so on..the real data is pretty big so it is causing a bit problem..Do someone have an idea out there..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumcount function of pandas. Example usage is available on the link.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['b'], ['b'], ['a']],
                  columns=['A'])

df.groupby('A').cumcount(ascending=True)
```

The alternative solution is something like that;

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('name').date.apply(lambda x: x.shift().cumsum())
```

I strongly suggest parse date to different columns for doing that. Then you should add `.astype(int)` and take care of `NaN` values.

[cumcount in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

Answer (score 0):

First ensure your `date` column is datetime type. Then get all possible dates in ascending sequence. At last, increase the date window and export `date` column value in date window to csv.

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

dates = df['date'].sort_values().unique()

for i in range(1, len(dates)):
    df_ = df[df['date'].isin(dates[:i])]
    df_.to_csv(f'file{i}.csv', index=False)
```